# How to implement browser-aliases for complex URLs

Tags: browser, bookmarks

I wrote a CLI tool that takes a config file containing url templates

```
id          url
------------------------------------------------------
hn          https://hn.algolia.com/?q=$0
somesite    https://somesite/?q=$0&someotherqueryparam
```

and opens the urls in the browser

```sh
hl hn somesearchstring
hl somesite hi

# opens the following urls
# https://hn.algolia.com/?q=somesearchstring
# https://somesite/?q=hi&someotherqueryparam
```

I believe that browsers might support this natively in the browser (*not using site search*)

Is it possible to use dynamic bookmarks (if they still exist native to the browser), bookmarklets, or another technique to type in the following strings and open the urls above?

```
hl hn somesearchstring
hl somesite somesearchstring
```

If this is possible, I'll rewire my CLI tool to generate the bookmarks / other browser artifacts to run these aliases directly in the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Self-answer: this is possible by adding a search-engine for each shortcut. This can be done by sending

```
chrome.send('searchEngineEditStarted', [-1]);
chrome.send('searchEngineEditCompleted', [id, name, url]);
```

for each shortcut, from `chrome://settings/searchEngines`

Comment: Just for added clarity, in your example, your `id` is the search engine name, `name` is the search engine keyword/shortcut, and `url` is the URL (with `%s` for substitutions).